JSON to XML using XSLT with changing the content
I want to convert existing json file to xml file and some values:
json file:
    {
    "Code": "111",
    "UnitCode": "XYZ",
    "valueCond": {
        "ir": "#001",
        "nk": "portal"
    },
    "property": "AFB139"
    }


desire xml file:
    <map>
    <Code>111</Code>
    <UnitCode>XYZ</UnitCode>
    <valueCond> 
        <ir>#001_1234</ir>
        <nk>portal:zeo</nk>
    <valueCond>
    <property>AFB139<property>
    </map>

I use function json-to-xml, but in the result I get only values without name of elements...How in the result file I can have xml structure with element and values
    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:variable name="json-as-xml" select="json-to-xml(unparsed-text($input-json)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$json-as-xml"/>
    
    </xsl:template>


Well, you need to transform the result of json-to-xml further e.g.
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:variable name="json-as-xml" select="json-to-xml(unparsed-text($input-json)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$json-as-xml"/>

  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="map[not(@key)]">
    <map>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </map>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[@key]">
    <xsl:element name="{@key}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

Result is e.g.
<map>
   <UnitCode>XYZ</UnitCode>
   <property>AFB139</property>
   <valueCond>
      <ir>#001</ir>
      <nk>portal</nk>
   </valueCond>
   <Code>111</Code>
</map>

Add further templates like e.g.
  <xsl:template match="string[@key = 'ir' and . = '#001']">
    <xsl:element name="{@key}">{. || '_1234'}</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="string[@key = 'nk' and . = 'portal']">
    <xsl:element name="{@key}">{. || ':zeo'}</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

to change those values and get e.g.
<map>
   <UnitCode>XYZ</UnitCode>
   <property>AFB139</property>
   <valueCond>
      <ir>#001_1234</ir>
      <nk>portal:zeo</nk>
   </valueCond>
   <Code>111</Code>
</map>

Online fiddle example (JSON is inlined there as string param value).

Martin, thanks a lot for very helpful answer. Additional question, as a result - I have attribute @xmlns="" for each element, for example -
'XYZ'
How can I avoid this?

@Shud, for me the result is as shown in the answer, there are no xmlns undeclarations. So either you have changed the code or the input in some way you would need to share or you are using an XSLT processor and/or environment where something is different, then you need to share enough information to allow us to reproduce the problem.

I don't think I would use json-to-xml for this. I would do it "by hand":
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template" expand-text="yes">
  <xsl:variable name="json" select="json-doc(...)"/>
  <map>
    <Code>{$json?Code}</Code>
    <UnitCode>{$json?UnitCode}</UnitCode>
    <valueCond> 
        <ir>{$json?valueCond?ir}</ir>
        <nk>{$json?valueCond?nk}</nk>
    <valueCond>
    <property>{$json?property}<property>
  </map>
</xsl:template>

(Adding any data changes that you need to make at the same time - these aren't clear in your requirements.)
